# I am not able to create any resource using terraform, I have installed terraform in windows 11 and tried, please let me know what went wrong?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Terraform CODE:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
  access_key = "*********************"
  secret_key = "***************************"
}

resource "aws_vpc" "mainvpc" {
  cidr_block = "10.1.0.0/16"
  tags = {
    Name = "example"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "main" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.mainvpc.id
  cidr_block = "10.0.1.0/24"

  tags = {
    Name = "Main"
  }
}
```

Terminal Output:

```
\`PS C:\\Users\\surya\\Documents\\Terraform_project\> terraform init

Initializing the backend...

Initializing provider plugins...

Terraform has been successfully initialized!

You may now begin working with Terraform. Try running "terraform plan" to see
any changes that are required for your infrastructure. All Terraform commands
should now work.

If you ever set or change modules or backend configuration for Terraform,
rerun this command to reinitialize your working directory. If you forget, other
commands will detect it and remind you to do so if necessary.
PS C:\\Users\\surya\\Documents\\Terraform_project\> terraform plan

No changes. Your infrastructure matches the configuration.

Terraform has compared your real infrastructure against your configuration and found no differences, so no changes are needed.
PS C:\\Users\\surya\\Documents\\Terraform_project\> terraform apply

No changes. Your infrastructure matches the configuration.

Terraform has compared your real infrastructure against your configuration and found no differences, so no changes are needed.

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.\`
```

Comment: Are you sure you are in the right directory? Have you saved the file after making changes?

Comment: Oh! my god I didn't save it, it is working NOW  " Thank You!.

I was following the video, he didn't save but worked.